# How do I create a view in Snowflake with an autoincrement column

Tags: sql, database, auto-increment, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a view in snowflake but I need to add an autoincrement column that does not exist in the table

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using a separate `sequence` object, e.g.:

```
create or replace table tab(i int) as select * from values('100'),('200'),('300');
create sequence seq;
create or replace view v as select i, seq.nextval as autoinc from tab;
```

However, since the content of a view is **not materialized**. So, if you select from that view, **the `autoinc` column will each time have a new value**, e.g.

```
select * from v;
-----+---------+
  I  | NEXTVAL |
-----+---------+
 100 | 1       |
 200 | 2       |
 300 | 3       |
-----+---------+

select * from v;
-----+---------+
  I  | NEXTVAL |
-----+---------+
 100 | 4       |
 200 | 5       |
 300 | 6       |
-----+---------+
```

If this works for you, that's ok. You could also re-create the sequence before each select from view:

```
select * from v;
-----+---------+
  I  | NEXTVAL |
-----+---------+
 100 | 1       |
 200 | 2       |
 300 | 3       |
-----+---------+

create or replace sequence seq;
------------------------------------+
               status               |
------------------------------------+
 Sequence SEQ successfully created. |
------------------------------------+

select * from v;
-----+---------+
  I  | NEXTVAL |
-----+---------+
 100 | 1       |
 200 | 2       |
 300 | 3       |
-----+---------+
```

However, there is **no guarantee** that the same record will get the same value with each view evaluation. Also, note that sequences are not guaranteed to produce a dense list of numbers (there might be holes).

Bottom line - it's best to have a table with an `autoincrement` column.

Answer (score 0):

Put a Row_Number Partition by clause into your query.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  [ PARTITION BY <expr1> [, <expr2> ... ] ]
  ORDER BY <expr3> [ , <expr4> ... ] [ { ASC | DESC } ]
  )
```

[Link to ROW_NUMBER Docs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html)